# loading localization files from server at run time?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, localization, resx

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 application which has 2 supported languages. The strings for each language are in separate resx files and everything is fine. Because the app is available on all three platforms and we want to be able to change any string at anytime, we are considering making the localized strings stored on the server and our app loads it on app launch. Is this possible with resx file ? Is there an alternative way that would work other than resx files.

Any help is appreciated